# How to plot a surface having equation $-(x^2y)/2 + 16.7 yz =0 $ for a set of (x,y,z) values?

Tags: plotting

I have a surface $-(x^2y)/2 + 16.7 yz =0 $ and I want to plot this surface for a given set of (x,y,z) values.Let us say that set of (x,y,z) values are

```
(x,y,z)={{10., 10., 10.}, {-5.56506, -0.826194, 29.6758}, {-0.52783, -0.676796, 14.6942}, {8.3787, 12.6581, 19.9009}, {5.88768, 0.866465, 30.2086}, {0.401074, 0.436885, 15.0451}, {-7.33434, -11.0017, 19.4259}, {-6.85204, -1.80913,  31.0188}, {-2.24681, -3.44669, 14.9831}, {6.88808, 12.5021, 12.2613}, {-7.17746, -0.544312, 32.7429}}
```

These values i got by solving 3 different differential equations with initial conditions (x0,y0,z0)=(10,10,10). As we can see these generated values are random i mean there is no ascending order or descending order. How can I plot the above given surface $-(x^2y)/2 + 16.7 yz =0 $ using these randomly generated values??

Comment: You give a set of points with 3 coordinates $(x,y,z)$, but the equation itself depends only on $x$ and $z$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bmf OP doesn't post the correct equation: `\[Minus](x^2/2) + 16.7 z /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> #] & /@ {{10., 10., 
   10.}, {-5.56506, -0.826194, 29.6758}, {-0.52783, -0.676796, 14.6942}, {8.3787, 
   12.6581, 19.9009}, {5.88768, 0.866465, 30.2086}, {0.401074, 0.436885, 
   15.0451}, {-7.33434, -11.0017, 19.4259}, {-6.85204, -1.80913, 
   31.0188}, {-2.24681, -3.44669, 14.9831}, {6.88808, 12.5021, 
   12.2613}, {-7.17746, -0.544312, 32.7429}}`

Comment: @xzczd yup, I know ;) Just pointed it out so they can fix the question

Comment: may be try `ListPointPlot3D[data]` or `ListPlot3D[data,Mesh->All]` or `ListSurfacePlot3D[data]`

Comment: @bmf Thanks for pointing out. Now, I have changed the equation.

Answer (score 1):

As your function only depends on x and z, you may neglect the y component and draw a Plot3D Graphics from x, z and f[x,z]:

First create data points: {x,z,f[x,y]}:

```
pts = {#[[1]], #[[3]], -#[[1]]^2 + 16.7 #[[3]]} & /@ {{10., 10., 
    10.}, {-5.56506, -0.826194, 29.6758}, {-0.52783, -0.676796, 
    14.6942}, {8.3787, 12.6581, 19.9009}, {5.88768, 0.866465, 
    30.2086}, {0.401074, 0.436885, 15.0451}, {-7.33434, -11.0017, 
    19.4259}, {-6.85204, -1.80913, 31.0188}, {-2.24681, -3.44669, 
    14.9831}, {6.88808, 12.5021, 12.2613}, {-7.17746, -0.544312, 
    32.7429}}
```

Then you can draw the surface and mark the points e.g. by small sticks:

```
Show[Plot3D[-x^2/2 + 16.7 z, {x, -10, 33}, {z, 10, 33}],
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.01], Green, 
   Line[{# - {0, 0, 50}, # + {0, 0, 50}}] & /@ pts}]
 ]
```

[image]